# Get arity of curried function

Tags: lodash

How does one get the arity of a curried function in lodash?

Consider:

`const uniqueBy = curry((predicate, data) => {});`

In a test I'm writing I'd like to know the arity of the `uniqueBy` function as well as the arity of a partially applied `uniqueBy` function.

`const partiallyApplied = uniqueBy(x => x.get('name'));
expect(partiallyApplied.length).to.equal(1);`

and so on.

In plain JS we can do `uniqueBy.length`. Doing the same in lodash always returns `0` because we end up calculating the arity of the `wrapper()` function.

Is there a defined way of doing this in lodash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash stores the arity of its curried and other function wrappers in metadata of a WeakMap which is not exposed. It avoids creating functions with a .length since that's extra overhead (usually conditional up to like 10 args) and can be complicated by ES6 default params.

Comment: Thanks for confirming John-David. Much appreciated.